# Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement' in React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, react-testing-library

> I am using React-testing-library and getting an error on the last line which is:
>   **expect (title.value).toBe("testtitle");})})** . The error message is **Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'**. How can I rectify this error message in order to write this code efficiently?

**Testfile**

```
  <Router history={history}>
            <Route render={(props) => 
            <NewQuestion {...props} onSave={jest.fn()}/>}/>
        </Router>)
    const title= getByPlaceholderText("What's your question? Be specific");
    fireEvent.change(title, {target: {value: "testtitle"}})
    expect (title.value).toBe("testtitle");})})
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You should cast the `title` variable to `HTMLInputElement` to actually be able to have the `value` property. Try the following code:

```
const title = getByPlaceholderText("test") as HTMLInputElement;
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case,

```js
  expect(
    screen.getByLabelText(/barInput/).value,
  ).toEqual('bar value');
```

throw Error "Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'."

I solved it by just adding generics `HTMLInputElement`

```js
  expect(
    screen.getByLabelText<HTMLInputElement>(/barInput/).value,
  ).toEqual('bar value');
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to casting is to use [`instanceof` narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#instanceof-narrowing):

```
const title = getByPlaceholderText("test");
if (!(title instanceof HTMLInputElement)) {
  throw new AssertionError("expected title to be an HTMLInputElement");
}
// Now TypeScript knows title is an HTMLInputElement if we made it here.
expect(title.value).toBe("foo");
```

This is more code than casting but arguably a better test because we'll get an explicit failure if the element returned is not an `HTMLInputElement`. This approach is inspired by this [`dom-testing-library` github issue comment](https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/issues/65#issuecomment-407866947).

If you have to do this type of check in multiple spots, you can make an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) for reuse:

```
function assertIsHTMLInputElement(
  val: unknown
): asserts val is HTMLInputElement {
  if (!(val instanceof HTMLInputElement)) {
    throw new AssertionError(`expected ${val} to be an HTMLInputElement`);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but just with href.

I used `HTMLAnchorElement` to solve the error:

```
const button = screen.getByRole<HTMLAnchorElement>('button');
expect(button.href).toContain('/something/awesome');
```