# React testing library in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, testing, react-testing-library

I'm following a tutorial on React.js testing Library and trying to follow along in Typescript.
Although after following along with the first test I'm already encountering a few issues and am wondering what should be different in a test written in Typescript.

App.ts

```
function App() {
    return (
        <div className="container my-5">
            <form>
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <label htmlFor="email" className="form-label">
                        Email Address
                    </label>
                    <input
                        type="email"
                        id="email"
                        name="email"
                        className="form-control"
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <label htmlFor="password" className="form-label">
                        Password
                    </label>
                    <input
                        type="password"
                        id="password"
                        name="password"
                        className="form-control"
                    />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

App.test.tsx

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import App from "./App";

test("inputs should be initially empty", () => {
    render(<App />);
    const emailInputElement = screen.getByRole("textbox");
    const passwordInputElement = screen.getByLabelText(/password/);
    expect(emailInputElement.value).toBe("");
    expect(passwordInputElement.value).toBe("");
});
```

I'm receiving an error "Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement" on:

```
expect(emailInputElement.value).toBe("");
expect(passwordInputElement.value).toBe("");
```

Do these need to be explained differently on Typescript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59986806/property-value-does-not-exist-on-type-htmlelement-in-react-testing-library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this error because `screen.getByRole` and `screen.getByLabelText` returns `HTMLElement` object and it doesn´t have `value` prop.

There are 2 ways to get it working:

1. explicitly define the return type as `HTMLInputElement` (it has value prop).

```js
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import App from "./App";

test("inputs should be initially empty", () => {
  render(<App />);

   const emailInputElement = screen.getByRole<HTMLInputElement>("textbox");
   const passwordInputElement = screen.getByLabelText<HTMLInputElement>(/password/i);

   expect(emailInputElement.value).toBe("");
   expect(passwordInputElement.value).toBe("");
});
```

2. Use `@testing-library/jest-dom` library -> it provides a set of custom jest matchers that you can use to extend jest. You can check more [here](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom).

```js
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import App from "./App";

test("inputs should be initially empty", () => {
  render(<App />);

   const emailInputElement = screen.getByRole("textbox");
   const passwordInputElement = screen.getByLabelText(/password/i);  

   expect(emailInputElement).toHaveValue("");
   expect(passwordInputElement).toHaveValue("");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define type for both text box as `HTMLInputElement` also where you are targeting password in your actual code it's case sensitive so always use regular expression to avoid tests failing ie  `(/password/i)`

```
  render(<App/>);
  const emailInputElement: HTMLInputElement = screen.getByRole("textbox");
  const passwordInputElement: HTMLInputElement =
    screen.getByLabelText(/password/i);
  expect(emailInputElement.value).toBe("");
  expect(passwordInputElement.value).toBe("");
});
```